# Default RDFS inference in Virtuoso 7.x

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, inference

This is a question about simple RDFS inference in Virtuoso 7.1 and DBpedia. I have a Virtuoso instance which was installed using this [link](https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/11/10/setting-up-a-local-dbpedia-2014-mirror-with-virtuoso-7-1-0/) as a reference. Now if I query the endpoint with the following query :

```
Select ?s 
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Cricketer> . }
```

I get a list of Cricketers that are present in DBpedia. Suppose I want all the athletes (all sports and cricketers included, where Athlete is `rdfs:superClassOf` Cricketer), I just try the query

```
Select ?s 
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> . }
```

For this I get all the correct answers. However I have an issue with `rdfs:subPropertyOf`. For example the property `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital>` is the sub-property of `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/administrativeHeadCity>`. So suppose I want all the capitals and the administrative head cities and I issue the query

```
Select ?s ?o 
where { ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/administrativeHeadCity> ?o . }
```

I get zero results. Why is it that subproperty inference isn't working in DBpedia? Is there something else that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed a couple of things.

First, Virtuoso is at [7.2.4 as of April 2016](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews), and this version is strongly recommended over the old version from 2014, for many reasons.

@AKSW's advice about Property Paths will work much better with this later version, too.

Then, you *can* use inference on the DBpedia endpoint (including your local mirror), through [the `input:inference` pragma](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlruleintro/), as shown on the [live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DEFINE+input%3Ainference+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2Finference%2Frules%2Fdbpedia%23%22%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fplace+%3FHeadCity+%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A+++%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fplace++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FadministrativeHeadCity%3E++%3FHeadCity%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fplace+%3FHeadCity%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) of [the query shown below](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=DEFINE+input%3Ainference+%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2Finference%2Frules%2Fdbpedia%23%22%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fplace+%3FHeadCity+%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A+++%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Fplace++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FadministrativeHeadCity%3E++%3FHeadCity%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fplace+%3FHeadCity%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) --

```
DEFINE input:inference "http://dbpedia.org/resource/inference/rules/dbpedia#"

SELECT ?place ?HeadCity 
WHERE
  {
     ?place  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/administrativeHeadCity>  ?HeadCity
  }
ORDER BY ?place ?HeadCity
```

You can also see a list of [predefined inference rule sets](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?rdfinf).

And... more of the [relevant documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlruleexamples/).

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: This really solves the problem @TallTed. I would assume that one should be able to also use the pragma from Jena to query Virtuoso!

Comment: Yes, the pragma may be used in any SPARQL query that reaches Virtuoso through any connection. Depending on specific Virtuoso features you want to use, [you may need to bypass the Jena parser as described in our doc](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider#Bypass%20Jena/ARQ%20parser).

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic inference enabled in DBpedia. DBpedia itself is a dataset loaded into Virtuoso.

The reason that you get all instances with a superclass like `dbo:Athlete` is that subclass-inheritance is fully materialized in the current DBpedia dataset:

`(s rdf:type c1), (c1 rdfs:subClassOf c2) -> (s rdf:type c2)`

That means that for each individual `x`, the DBpedia dataset contains all the classes `C` it belongs to - in fact also the superclasses.

That procedure was **not** done for subproperty-inheritance, i.e.,

`(s p1 o), (p1 rdfs:subPropertyOf p2) -> (s p2 o)`

You can solve that problem with SPARQL 1.1 property paths:

```
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {
   ?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/administrativeHeadCity> .
   ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

Comment: Ah! that explains why the subPropertyOf wasn't working! I should have checked that earlier. Thanks a lot @AKSW!